# Apple In-App purchase - retrieve price for specific locale

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch

As the title suggests, I need to obtain an in-app product price in tier but for the U.S. App store, completely ignoring users current locale and settings.

In other words,
Get the USD price of a product even if users local is set to Russia/France/Whatever.

Thanks

Comment: Why? Then the display would be different to the price the user would pay.

Comment: Need it for analytics

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you need will be available in SKProductsRequest. If you implement an object with the SKRequestDelegate protocol you can obtain the prices. You can choose to hardcode the locale to US if you wish.

To setup the request:

```
NSSet* identifiers = [NSSet setWithObjects:inAppIdentiferOne, inAppIdentifierTwo, nil];

SKProductsRequest* productRequest= [[SKProductsRequest alloc] initWithProductIdentifiers:identifiers];
productRequest.delegate = self;
[productRequest start];
```

To handle the response:

```
-(void) productsRequest:(SKProductsRequest *)request didReceiveResponse:(SKProductsResponse *)response
{
     for(int i=0; i<response.products.count; i++)
     {
         SKProduct* instance = [response.products objectAtIndex:i];

         NSLog(@"IAP Desc: %@. Title: %@.", instance.localizedDescription, instance.localizedTitle);

         // This is where you can hardcode the US locale by setting a NSLocale type
         // I'm not 100% sure on how to set the NSLocale correctly, so currently this line sets localization
         NSLocale* locale = instance.priceLocale;

         NSNumberFormatter* fmtr = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];
         [fmtr setNumberStyle:NSNumberFormatterCurrencyStyle];
         [fmtr setLocale:locale];

         if([instance.productIdentifier isEqualToString:inAppIdentiferOne]) 
         {
             NSString* localizedCostString = [fmtr stringFromNumber:(instance.price)];
             NSString* productIdentifier = instance.productIdentifier;
         }
         else if([instance.productIdentifier isEqualToString:inAppIdentiferTwo]) 
         {
             NSString* localizedCostString = [fmtr stringFromNumber:(instance.price)];
             NSString* productIdentifier = instance.productIdentifier;
         }
     }
 }
```

There is a further optional function to handle failure of retrieving these identifiers you probably want to handle.

Comment: This just changes the formatter (so the currency symbol and style), not the data (the price number) actually returned by Apple...

Comment: Actually yeh I've just realized the price returned by Apple is already localized. So if you hardcode the formatter to show USD, then it's going to show inconsistent prices when it's supposed to represent another currency. It's a shame that Apple don't return the tier price for an IAP